# Using the SQLSRV Native Client in PHP does connection pooling affect @@IDENTITY in anyway?

Tags: sql-server, insert, connection-pooling, identity

I do not have an issue in test but I am wondering about a live environment with thousands of simultaneous users.

If I execute two queries separately:

```
insert into table (somecolumnname) values (somedata)
```

followed by

```
select @@IDENTITY as lastInsertId
```

This will get me the last insert ID to be used in other queries later on. The documentation on @@IDENTITY (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa933167(v=sql.80).aspx) says:

> The scope of the @@IDENTITY function is the local server on which it is executed.

If this is local server, if someone comes in and inserts another statement in the time it takes me to execute the second query then I will get the wrong insertID; even if it is within a transaction?

Secondly, I read a conflicting account here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187342.aspx):

```
The scope of the @@IDENTITY function is current session on the local server on which it is executed.
```

Therefore if @@IDENTITY is session based what exactly is a session when connecting using the native client and connection pooling? From my understanding of connection pooling, if a second user accesses the site while the first user is accessing my site; the nativec client will use the same connection instead of opening a second separate connection. If this is the case is this the same as sharing the session when it comes to @@IDENTITY meaning that inserts from other users can still affect the results?

It does sound like a transaction should ensure I get the right value from @@IDENTITY but I am finding it hard to find clear documentation telling me that this is the case and of course this is hard to test in a test environment.

I've tried executing both of the queries together using an absolute cursor:

```
inset into table (somecolumnname) values (somedata);select @@IDENTITY as lastindertid
```

But the problem is this is running through an abstraction function which appends the select @@identity query to the end to set a dirty global to the last insert id (i can't change this easily or I would). As there is no sqlsrv_last_result function there is no way for me to know if I am on the last result or not without moving the cursor too far and checking if it is null; but again this would require me to pull data from every query in a try:catch (to prevent errors pulling data from deletes for example) and then just use the last pull before the cursor returned null... this is of course extremely slow.

If someone has managed to test this or can point to somewhere where the definitions are not conflicting that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using @@IDENTITY? Ever? You should be using SCOPE_IDENTITY() and referencing it as part of the same batch. Better yet put this logic into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that the native client (unlike DBLIB) default to setting NOCOUNT off meaning that INSERTs return the number of affected rows as result sets which was causing me the original issue.

Immediately running "SET NOCOUNT ON" followed by using SCOPE_IDENTITY() within the same query batch seems to have solved the issue by not requiring me to run two separate queries in order to locate the select portion.

In the future more inserts will use stored procedures instead.